# How to access the value of a select Box as variable onChange inside another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to access the value of `#schooSelect` inside ajax so i can send some data to php onChange.

```
$.LoadBooks = function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#SchoolSelect', (function (e) {
        var SchoolVal = ($(this).val())
        $.LoadBooks()
    }))
    var SchoolVal = ($('#SchoolSelect').val())
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            data: SchoolVal
        },
        url: "../php/booksads.php"
    }).done(function (feedback) {
        $('#booksads').html(feedback)
    });
}
$.LoadBooks()
```

Comment: Why are you calling `$.LoadBooks` from inside the event handler? What will add the event handler again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is strangely structured. You are somehow "recursively" calling `$.LoadBooks` inside the event handler, which will cause a new event handler to be added to the element, which is certainly not what you want.

Just bind the event handler once, outside the function:

```
var loadBooks = function(schoolVal) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            data: schoolVal
        },
        url: "../php/booksads.php"
    }).done(function (feedback) {
        $('#booksads').html(feedback)
    });
}

$(document).on('change', '#SchoolSelect', function(e) {
    loadBooks($(this).val());
});
```

You can either pass the value of the select element to the function (as shown here) or call `var schoolVal = $('#SchoolSelect').val()` inside of it to get the value.

---

The convention is that only the name of  *constructor functions* start with a capital letter. And if your function is related to jQuery in particular, you shouldn't add it to `$`.

Comment: Where are you sending the value of selected item to ajax, can you just make the onChange select to alert it's value outside that function so i can access it from other functions, just that.

Comment: *"Where are you sending the value of selected item to ajax"* I pass the value as argument to the function `loadBooks($(this).val());` and inside the function I use `data: { data: schoolVal },`. *"can you just make the onChange select to alert it's value outside that function so i can access it from other functions"* There is no need for this. If you need the value somewhere else, just call `var value = $('#SchoolSelect').val();` to get the value.

Comment: I've added alert to Var LoadBooks on your Code, but on change that always alert the default value. It doesn't alert the new selected value rather the one which was the on load.

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pbEbE/. Maybe you are doing something else wrong.